# RESTful API endpoint for custom response data

Tags: rest, api-design

I am building a RESTful API where I have a resource named solar_systems. solar_sytems has id(int), system_size(int), system_cost(int) columns with many other columns.

I understand that API endpoints will be-

/v1/solar-systems  - for all systems

/v1/solar-systems/{id} - for a single system

And I have to pass query params for filter, search, sorting etc.

But what will be the best practice for API endpoints if I need some kind of custom data like if I need average system_cost for each system_size.

Will it be silly, if I use - /v1/solar-systems/average-system-cost?

Please I need your opinion from your experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not silly at all to use /v1/solar-systems/average-system-cost

It is easy to get caught up in the fact that technically the average-system-cost is not a resource. But it is a piece of data that is useful to retrieve. Ultimately the goal of REST is to make APIs that are understandable and readable. A specific endpoint that gets a useful piece of data definitely falls inside that.

Comment: Is it really the goal to have "readable" APIs? REST clients should NOT interpret URIs at all so the structure of an URI is not of importance to REST clients actually. What IS important though is that the URI is provided with a meaningful link relation name that hints the client what this URI can be used for. Think of relation names similar to `next`, `prev`, `first`, `last`, ... The ultimate goal in REST architectures IMO is the decoupling of clients from server APIs which gives servers the freedom to change and evolve without breaking clients.

Answer (score 0):

> Will it be silly, if I use `/v1/solar-systems/average-system-cost`?

The REST architecture *doesn't enforce any URI design* <sup>(see notes below)</sup>. It's totally up to you to pick the URIs that better identify your resources.

However I would probably use [*query parameters*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.4) to select the fields to be returned in the response. Something like `/v1/solar-systems?fields=average-system-cost`.

---

<sup>**Note 1:** The REST architectural style, described in the [chapter 5](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) of Roy T. Fielding's dissertation, defines a set of constraints that must be followed by the applications that follow such architecture. *However it says nothing about what the URLs must be like.*</sup>

<sup>**Note 2:** On the other hand, the *examples* of a [popular article](https://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html) written by Martin Fowler explaining a model defined by Leonard Richardson *suggest* a URL structure that looks friendly and easy to read.</sup>